# Create a script to open multiple terminal windows with some commands on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I want to create a script to open multiple terminals and each terminal calls a different command. For example one terminal calls dmesg and a few other terminals call another command. I also want to specify the size of the terminal window. (ie. the terminal displaying dmesg is on the left, the next one is next to the dmesg terminal and so fourth)

The example screenshot is below.
[image]
Thanks,

Comment: You already know that [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=GEOMETRY1 -- PROGRAM1 [ARG1...] &
gnome-terminal --geometry=GEOMETRY2 -- PROGRAM2 [ARG2...] &
gnome-terminal --geometry=GEOMETRY3 -- PROGRAM3 [ARG3...] &
```

see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html for details